# Algorithm for type checking ML-like pattern matching?

Tags: algorithm, haskell, ocaml, typechecking

How do you determine whether a given pattern is "good", specifically whether it is exhaustive and non-overlapping, for ML-style programming languages?

Suppose you have patterns like:

```
match lst with
  x :: y :: [] -> ...
  [] -> ...
```

or:

```
match lst with
  x :: xs -> ...
  x :: [] -> ...
  [] -> ...
```

A good type checker would warn that the first is not exhaustive and the second is overlapping. How would the type checker make those kinds of decisions in general, for arbitrary data types?

Comment: Pattern matching unrolling is normally done in a separate pass, after the type inference.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Here's a sketch of an algorithm. It's also the basis of Lennart Augustsson's celebrated technique for compiling pattern matching efficiently. (The [paper](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-15975-4_48) is in that incredible FPCA proceedings (LNCS 201) with oh so many hits.) The idea is to reconstruct an exhaustive, non-redundant analysis by repeatedly splitting the most general pattern into constructor cases.

In general, the problem is that your program has a possibly empty bunch of ‘actual’ patterns {p<sub>1</sub>, .., p<sub>n</sub>}, and you want to know if they cover a given ‘ideal’ pattern q. To kick off, take q to be a variable x. The invariant, initially satisfied and subsequently maintained, is that each p<sub>i</sub> is σ<sub>i</sub>q for some substitution σ<sub>i</sub> mapping variables to patterns.

How to proceed. If n=0, the bunch is empty, so you have a possible case q that isn't covered by a pattern. Complain that the ps are not exhaustive. If σ<sub>1</sub> is an injective *renaming* of variables, then p<sub>1</sub> catches every case that matches q, so we're warm: if n=1, we win; if n>1 then oops, there's no way p<sub>2</sub> can ever be needed. Otherwise, we have that for some variable x, σ<sub>1</sub>x is a constructor pattern. In that case split the problem into multiple subproblems, one for each constructor c<sub>j</sub> of x's type. That is, split the original q into multiple ideal patterns q<sub>j</sub> = [x:=c<sub>j</sub> y<sub>1</sub> .. y<sub>arity(c<sub>j</sub>)</sub>]q, and refine the patterns accordingly for each q<sub>j</sub> to maintain the invariant, dropping those that don't match.

Let's take the example with `{[], x :: y :: zs}` (using `::` for `cons`). We start with

```
  xs covering  {[], x :: y :: zs}
```

and we have [xs := []] making the first pattern an instance of the ideal. So we split xs, getting

```
  [] covering {[]}
  x :: ys covering {x :: y :: zs}
```

The first of these is justified by the empty injective renaming, so is ok. The second takes [x := x, ys := y :: zs], so we're away again, splitting ys, getting.

```
  x :: [] covering {}
  x :: y :: zs covering {x :: y :: zs}
```

and we can see from the first subproblem that we're banjaxed.

The overlap case is more subtle and allows for variations, depending on whether you want to flag up any overlap, or just patterns which are completely redundant in a top-to-bottom priority order. Your basic rock'n'roll is the same. E.g., start with

```
  xs covering {[], ys}
```

with [xs := []] justifying the first of those, so split. Note that we have to refine ys with constructor cases to maintain the invariant.

```
  [] covering {[], []}
  x :: xs covering {y :: ys}
```

Clearly, the first case is strictly an overlap. On the other hand, when we notice that refining an actual program pattern is needed to maintain the invariant, we can filter out those strict refinements that become redundant and check that at least one survives (as happens in the `::` case here).

So, the algorithm builds a set of ideal exhaustive overlapping patterns q in a way that's motivated by the actual program patterns p. You split the ideal patterns into constructor cases whenever the actual patterns demand more detail of a particular variable. If you're lucky, each actual pattern is covered by disjoint nonempty sets of ideal patterns and each ideal pattern is covered by just one actual pattern. The tree of case splits which yield the ideal patterns gives you the efficient jump-table driven compilation of the actual patterns.

The algorithm I've presented is clearly terminating, but if there are datatypes with no constructors, it can fail to accept that the empty set of patterns is exhaustive. This is a serious issue in dependently typed languages, where exhaustiveness of conventional patterns is undecidable: the sensible approach is to allow "refutations" as well as equations. In Agda, you can write (), pronounced "my Aunt Fanny", in any place where no constructor refinement is possible, and that absolves you from the requirement to complete the equation with a return value. Every exhaustive set of patterns can be made *recognizably* exhaustive by adding in enough refutations.

Anyhow, that's the basic picture.

Comment: I'm not sure what 'banjaxed' means, but it doesn't sound good. I did run across references to 'Compiling pattern matching' by Lennart Augustsson, but I have not been able to find a copy.  Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Roughly speaking, "banjaxed" means "confounded" or "broken beyond repair". It's an Irish thing. Meanwhile, Lennart's paper is behind a paywall at http://www.springerlink.com/content/y647423656557505/ I don't know if there are cheaper options out there.

Comment: I don't understand what your aunt has to do with this whole pattern matching business :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is some code from a non-expert.  It shows what the problem looks like if you restrict your patterns to list constructors.  In other words, the patterns can only be used with lists that contain lists.  Here are some lists like that: `[]`, `[[]]`, `[[];[]]`.

If you enable `-rectypes` in your OCaml interpreter, this set of lists has a single type: `('a list) as 'a.`

```
type reclist = ('a list) as 'a
```

Here's a type for representing patterns that match against the `reclist` type:

```
type p = Nil | Any | Cons of p * p
```

To translate an OCaml pattern into this form, first rewrite using (::).  Then replace []
with Nil, _ with Any, and (::) with Cons.  So the pattern `[] :: _` translates to
`Cons (Nil, Any)`

Here is a function that matches a pattern against a reclist:

```
let rec pmatch (p: p) (l: reclist) =
    match p, l with
    | Any, _ -> true
    | Nil, [] -> true
    | Cons (p', q'), h :: t -> pmatch p' h && pmatch q' t
    | _ -> false
```

Here's how it looks in use.  Note the use of `-rectypes`:

```
$ ocaml312 -rectypes
        Objective Caml version 3.12.0

# #use "pat.ml";;
type p = Nil | Any | Cons of p * p
type reclist = 'a list as 'a
val pmatch : p -> reclist -> bool = <fun>
# pmatch (Cons(Any, Nil)) [];;
- : bool = false
# pmatch (Cons(Any, Nil)) [[]];;
- : bool = true
# pmatch (Cons(Any, Nil)) [[]; []];;
- : bool = false
# pmatch (Cons (Any, Nil)) [ [[]; []] ];;
- : bool = true
#
```

The pattern `Cons (Any, Nil)` should match any list of length 1, and it definitely seems to be working.

So then it seems fairly straightforward to write a function `intersect` that takes two patterns and returns a pattern that matches the intersection of what is matched by the two patterns.  Since the patterns might not intersect at all, it returns `None` when there's no intersection and `Some p` otherwise.

```
let rec inter_exc pa pb =
    match pa, pb with
    | Nil, Nil -> Nil
    | Cons (a, b), Cons (c, d) -> Cons (inter_exc a c, inter_exc b d)
    | Any, b -> b
    | a, Any -> a
    | _ -> raise Not_found

let intersect pa pb =
    try Some (inter_exc pa pb) with Not_found -> None

let intersectn ps =
    (* Intersect a list of patterns.
     *)
    match ps with
    | [] -> None
    | head :: tail ->
        List.fold_left
            (fun a b -> match a with None -> None | Some x -> intersect x b)
            (Some head) tail
```

As a simple test, intersect the pattern `[_, []]` against the pattern `[[], _]`.
The former is the same as `_ :: [] :: []`, and so is `Cons (Any, Cons (Nil, Nil))`.
The latter is the same as `[] :: _ :: []`, and so is `Cons (Nil, (Cons (Any, Nil))`.

```
# intersect (Cons (Any, Cons (Nil, Nil))) (Cons (Nil, Cons (Any, Nil)));;
- : p option = Some (Cons (Nil, Cons (Nil, Nil)))
```

The result looks pretty right: `[[], []]`.

It seems like this is enough to answer the question about overlapping patterns.  Two patterns overlap if their intersection is not `None`.

For exhaustiveness you need to work with a list of patterns.  Here is a function
`exhaust` that tests whether a given list of patterns is exhaustive:

```
let twoparts l =
    (* All ways of partitioning l into two sets.
     *)
    List.fold_left
        (fun accum x ->
            let absent = List.map (fun (a, b) -> (a, x :: b)) accum
            in
                List.fold_left (fun accum (a, b) -> (x :: a, b) :: accum)
                    absent accum)
        [([], [])] l

let unique l =
   (* Eliminate duplicates from the list.  Makes things
    * faster.
    *)
   let rec u sl=
        match sl with
        | [] -> []
        | [_] -> sl
        | h1 :: ((h2 :: _) as tail) ->
            if h1 = h2 then u tail else h1 :: u tail
    in
        u (List.sort compare l)

let mkpairs ps =
    List.fold_right
        (fun p a -> match p with Cons (x, y) -> (x, y) :: a | _ -> a) ps []

let rec submatches pairs =
    (* For each matchable subset of fsts, return a list of the
     * associated snds.  A matchable subset has a non-empty
     * intersection, and the intersection is not covered by the rest of
     * the patterns.  I.e., there is at least one thing that matches the
     * intersection without matching any of the other patterns.
     *)
    let noncovint (prs, rest) =
        let prs_firsts = List.map fst prs in
        let rest_firsts = unique (List.map fst rest) in
        match intersectn prs_firsts with
        | None -> false
        | Some i -> not (cover i rest_firsts)
    in let pairparts = List.filter noncovint (twoparts pairs)
    in
        unique (List.map (fun (a, b) -> List.map snd a) pairparts)

and cover_pairs basepr pairs =
    cover (fst basepr) (unique (List.map fst pairs)) &&
        List.for_all (cover (snd basepr)) (submatches pairs)

and cover_cons basepr ps =
    let pairs = mkpairs ps
    in let revpair (a, b) = (b, a)
    in
        pairs <> [] &&
        cover_pairs basepr pairs &&
        cover_pairs (revpair basepr) (List.map revpair pairs)

and cover basep ps =
    List.mem Any ps ||
        match basep with
        | Nil -> List.mem Nil ps
        | Any -> List.mem Nil ps && cover_cons (Any, Any) ps
        | Cons (a, b) -> cover_cons (a, b) ps

let exhaust ps =
    cover Any ps
```

A pattern is like a tree with `Cons` in the internal nodes and `Nil` or `Any` at the leaves.  The basic idea is that a set of patterns is exhaustive if you always reach `Any` in at least one of the patterns (no matter what the input looks like).  And along the way, you need to see both Nil and Cons at each point.  If you reach `Nil` at the same spot in all the patterns, it means there's a longer input that won't be matched by any of them.  On the other hand, if you see just `Cons` at the same spot in all the patterns, there's an input that ends at that point that won't be matched.

The difficult part is checking for exhaustiveness of the two subpatterns of a Cons.  This code works the way I do when I check by hand: it finds all the different subsets that could match at the left, then makes sure that the corresponding right subpatterns are exhaustive in each case.  Then the same with left and right reversed.  Since I'm a nonexpert (more obvious to me all the time), there are probably better ways to do this.

Here is a session with this function:

```
# exhaust [Nil];;
- : bool = false
# exhaust [Any];;
- : bool = true
# exhaust [Nil; Cons (Nil, Any); Cons (Any, Nil)];;
- : bool = false
# exhaust [Nil; Cons (Any, Any)];;
- : bool = true
# exhaust [Nil; Cons (Any, Nil); Cons (Any, (Cons (Any, Any)))];;
- : bool = true
```

I checked this code against 30,000 randomly generated patterns, and so I have some confidence that it's right.  I hope these humble observations may prove to be of some use.

Answer (score -1):

I believe the pattern sub-language is simple enough that it's easy to analyze.  This is the reason for requiring patterns to be "linear" (each variable can appear only once), and so on.  With these restrictions, every pattern is a projection from a kind of nested tuple space to a restricted set of tuples.  I don't think it's too difficult to check for exhaustiveness and overlap in this model.

Comment: I can see how the liner requirement makes it possible, but I can't see how to do it.

Comment: The question: how do you check for exhaustiveness and overlap?  This answer: it's possible.

Comment: Possibly a fair complaint.  I thought it was useful to think of the way a pattern is designed to be a fairly simple slice through the space of possibilities.  Doing efficient matching is a harder problem.   But apologies for not being more helpful.  In the meantime seems like pigworker gave a great answer.

Comment: (I added a second answer that gives working code for a much simplified version of the problem.   --J)