# Is it possible to debug pattern matching in a Haskell function?

Tags: debugging, haskell, pattern-matching

I have defined a type

```
data Expr = 
    Const Double
    | Add Expr Expr
    | Sub Expr Expr
```

and declared it as an instance of `Eq` typeclass:

```
instance Eq Expr where
    (Add (Const a1) (Const a2)) == Const b = a1+a2 == b
    (Add (Const a1) (Const a2)) == (Add (Const b1) (Const b2)) = a1+a2 == b1 + b2
```

Of course, the evaluation of the expression `Sub (Const 1) (Const 1) == Const 0` will fail. How can I debug at runtime the pattern matching process to spot that it's failing? I would like to see how Haskell takes the arguments of `==` and walks through the patterns. Is it possible at all?

Comment: GHC can detect the problem at compile-time. If you compile with `-Wall`, it will warn you about the incomplete pattern and show you which cases you missed.

Comment: The precise option is `-fwarn-incomplete-patterns`. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7883023/algorithm-for-type-checking-ml-like-pattern-matching to see how it works. By the way, in your example I recommend writing `eval :: Expr -> Double` and then `x == y = eval x == eval y`, but it is still rather nonstandard.

Comment: I know about the warnings. I would like to know, for example, why a pattern I think should match, doesn't.

Comment: @quant_dev: without any other information, I'd say that might be a question for StackOverflow :)

Comment: I'm not sure at all whether QuickCheck can help you with your issue because it will not enable you to step through haskell's matching process... however, since it gives you counterexamples for your tests, it could be of some help in identifying problems. See my answer.

Comment: Haskell is designed to catch errors at compile time, which is why it does not provide such a tool for run-time debugging.  While I'm not saying your question is "wrong", it is worth learning using the compile-time tools available, since they are significantly more powerful.  Also, you should seriously consider turning on `-fwarn-incomplete-patterns` and treat it like an error.  Forcing yourself to write a total function will help you learn what pattern matches you are missing.

Comment: @GabrielGonzalez The thing is that *when* writing a total function, such information "why this pattern didn't match when I think it should" would be very useful.

Comment: One thing you can do is just create a `Show` instance for the data type you are trying to pattern match to see what constructors it is actually built from.  Sometimes if something is not matching a pattern you think it should match, it's because it is actually not the value you think it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

edit: providing a real answer to the question...

I find the easiest way to see what patterns are matching is to add `trace` statements, like so:

```
import Debug.Trace

instance Eq Expr where
    (Add (Const a1) (Const a2)) == Const b = trace "Expr Eq pat 1" $ a1+a2 == b
    (Add (Const a1) (Const a2)) == (Add (Const b1) (Const b2)) = trace "Expr Eq pat 2" $ a1+a2 == b1 + b2
    -- catch any unmatched patterns
    l == r = error $ "Expr Eq failed pattern match. \n l: " ++ show l ++ "\n r: " ++ show r
```

If you don't include a final statement to catch any otherwise unmatched patterns, you'll get a runtime exception, but I find it's more useful to see what data you're getting.  Then it's usually simple to see why it doesn't match the previous patterns.

Of course you don't want to leave this in production code.  I only insert traces as necessary then remove them when I've finished.  You could also use CPP to leave them out of production builds.

I also want to say that I think pattern matching is the wrong way to go about this.  You'll end up with a combinatorial explosion in the number of patterns, which quickly grows unmanageable.  If you want to make a `Float` instance for `Expr` for example, you'll need several more primitive constructors.

Instead, you presumably have an interpreter function `interpret :: Expr -> Double`, or at least could write one.  Then you can define

```
instance Eq Expr where
  l == r = interpret l == interpret r
```

By pattern matching, you're essentially re-writing your interpret function in the `Eq` instance.  If you want to make an `Ord` instance, you'll end up re-writing the interpret function yet again.

Comment: Trace is the way to go. Evaluating to double won't work, because some instances of `Expr` can be functions.

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to get some examples on how the matching may fail, you could have a look at [QuickCheck](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/testing-and-quality-assurance.html). There's an example on the [manual](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~rjmh/QuickCheck/manual.html) (the size of test data) about generating and testing recursive data types that seems to perfectly suit your needs.

While the `-Wall` flag gives you a list of patterns non matched, a run of QuickCheck gives you examples of input data that lead your given proposition to failure.
For example, if I write a generator for your `Expr` and I give in input to `quickCheck` a proposition `prop_expr_eq :: Expr -> Bool` that checks if an `Expr` is equal to itself, I obtain very quickly `Const 0.0` as a first example of non-matching input.

```
import Test.QuickCheck
import Control.Monad

data Expr = 
    Const Double
    | Add Expr Expr
    | Sub Expr Expr
    deriving (Show)

instance Eq Expr where
    (Add (Const a1) (Const a2)) == Const b = a1+a2 == b
    (Add (Const a1) (Const a2)) == (Add (Const b1) (Const b2)) = a1+a2 == b1 + b2

instance Arbitrary Expr where
    arbitrary = sized expr'
      where
        expr' 0 = liftM Const arbitrary
        expr' n | n > 0 = 
            let subexpr = expr' (n `div` 2)
            in oneof [liftM Const arbitrary,
                      liftM2 Add subexpr subexpr,
                      liftM2 Sub subexpr subexpr]

prop_expr_eq :: Expr -> Bool
prop_expr_eq e = e == e
```

As you see, running the test gives you a counterexample to prove that your equality test is wrong. I know this may be a little bit an overkill, but the advantage if you write things good is that you also get unit tests for your code that look at arbitrary properties, not only pattern matching exhaustiveness.

```
*Main> quickCheck prop_expr_eq
*** Failed! Exception: 'test.hs:(11,5)-(12,81): Non-exhaustive patterns in function ==' (after 1 test):  
Const 0.0
```

PS: Another good reading about unit testing with QuickCheck is in the free book [real world haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/testing-and-quality-assurance.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can break your complex pattern into simpler patterns and use `trace` to see what's going on.  Something like this:

```
instance Eq Expr where
    x1 == x2 | trace ("Top level: " ++ show (x, y1)) True,
               Add x11 x12 <- x1,
               trace ("First argument Add: " ++ show (x11, x12)) True,
               Const a1 <- x11,
               trace ("Matched first Const: " ++ show a1) True,
               Const a2 <- x12,
               trace ("Matched second Const: " ++ show a2) True,
               Const b <- x2
               trace ("Second argument Const: " ++ show b) True
             = a1+a2 == b
```

It's a bit desperate, but desperate times calls for desperate measures. :)
As you get used to Haskell you rarely, if ever, need to do this.