# About the pattern matching algorithm in OCaml

Tags: functional-programming, pattern-matching, ocaml

I am writing a compiler for a functional language I designed with OCaml. I want my little language to have the feature of pattern matching, however, I got stuck in coming up with an algorithm to implement it. It seems really complicated as I dig into the problem. I can't find much useful information about the corresponding algorithm with google. I will be appreciated if someone can give me some hint or point me to the resources. Or are there any tricks to take advantage of OCaml's power in pattern matching to solve this problem so that I don't need to implement it? Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's a few good papers on compiling pattern matching by some of the people behind OCaml. In particular see [Compiling Pattern Matching to Good Decision Trees](http://www.cs.tufts.edu/~nr/cs257/archive/luc-maranget/jun08.pdf) and [Optimizing Pattern Matching](http://pauillac.inria.fr/~maranget/papers/opat/pat.ps.gz). It might also be useful to go over [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7883023/algorithm-for-type-checking-ml-like-pattern-matching).