# OCaml order of pattern matches best practice

Tags: pattern-matching, ocaml

From a performance standpoint, I was wondering if the order of patterns matched affects the efficiency of the function, or it has more to do with the proportion of different matches expected (i.e. if one pattern happens way more than the others, it should appear earlier).

```
(* a function to return the smaller of two int options, or None if both are None. If exactly one argument is None, return the other. *)

let min_option (x: int option) (y: int option) : int option =
  match x, y with
    None, None -> None
    | Some x, None -> Some x
    | None, Some y -> Some y
    | Some x, Some y -> if x < y then Some x else Some y

let () = assert((min_option (Some 10) (Some 11)) = Some 10);;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [About the pattern matching algorithm in OCaml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20233019/about-the-pattern-matching-algorithm-in-ocaml)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pattern matching algorithms in OCaml are very clever, so that you don't need to bother about order of matches. Start reading from this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20233019/about-the-pattern-matching-algorithm-in-ocaml) if you're interested in a subject.

There're some exception to the above rule: first, the semantics of your function may depend on the order of matches, if they overlap; second, if you pattern match on data, like strings, or integers then it will be compiled to somewhat resembling `if/else` series, with some [optimizations](http://caml.inria.fr/mantis/view.php?id=6269).

And finally asking the original question, there is no known to me best practices on how to write pattern-matches in efficient way.

#### Update:

Just in case, I obviously think that the provided example is synthetic, but for those who will read us in future. You don't need to write this function at all, as pervasive's `min` is universally polymorphic function already has the expected behavior on options. So your function is doing exactly the same (semantically) as `min x y`. But, if you're really interested in optimization, for example, if you're using this in a tight loop, then you can rewrite it like this:

```
let min x y : int option =
  match x, y with
  | v, None | None, v -> v
  | Some p, Some q -> if p < q then x else y
```

That will yield out an effective code, that will  not perform a C-call to polymorphic comparison function, and do not perform any allocations. But as always, you should trace your program to figure out, that this function is indeed a bottleneck.

Comment: This is indeed the case for sum types, it can be turned into a succession of `if` when you match on other data.

Answer (score 2):

This is not really related to your question, but if you care about performances, you should probably write your match a bit differently:

```
match x, y with
  | v, None
  | None, v -> v
  | (Some x as v1), (Some y as v2) -> if x < y then v1 else v2
```

That way you can avoid the allocation of the `Some` block.

Comment: Would it be possible for the compiler to detect such situation and avoid the allocation? Eg by using the same algorithm which check if a match is exhaustive, and see that in all cases the same computation is performed? (Perhaps that question should be asked formally?)

Comment: there is no need for parens . Also this can be rewritten withoud `as`, e.g.: ` | Some p, Some q -> if p < q then x else y`

Comment: @didierc, OCaml right now misses many optimization opportunities, mostly because that do not have an army of postdocs, as in haskell. The good news is that even without lots of optimization, OCaml is still very fast, and that means that it has a great potential

Comment: Thank you @ivg. However, I was not asking about the availability of resources, but rather the technical feasibility of such idea. Given Pierre Chambart's work on the compiler, I was hoping he could shed some light on the matter.

Comment: I think that it can be optimized out as a common subexpression. I personally think that it is possible. That's why I was talking about resources, because for my understanding there is no technical problem here

Comment: @ivg thank you again. I do believe too that CSE should provide the necessary basis for this to work. Regarding resources, I understand very well that there is a lack of manpower for these things, although the work done by the community is already outstanding (the new gc profiler for instance looks impressive).

Comment: This optimization is possible, but it is not completely trivial given the state of the current compiler: To be able to keep the value, we must ensure that removing the allocation won't change the semantics. This is not the case for instance if Some could be a mutable block. That means that this optimization needs type informations, but the current optimization passes are after type erasing.