# Haskell stripping function of syntactic sugar

Tags: haskell, syntactic-sugar

I'm wondering how would the following function look without any syntactic sugar:

```
tails1 :: [a] -> [[a]]
tails1 [] = [[]]
tails1 xs@(x:xs') = xs:tails1 xs'
```

I'm mostly concerned with the usage of the @ operator, I've tried what follows, but that's obviously not the correct way

```
tails1 ((:) x ((:) xs' [])) = xs:tails1 xs'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need to understand the list data type.
Here are the list data constructors:

```
[] :: [a]
(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]
```

where:

1. [] create an empty list
2. (:) takes an `a` , a list of `a` and returns a list of `a` with the new element appedned

Let say you have a list `[1,2,3,4]`.
This can be written as `(:) 1 ((:) 2 ((:) 3 ((:) 4 [])))`
In expression `x:xs'`, `x` hold `1` and `xs'` will hold `(:) 2 ((:) 3 ((:) 4 []))`.
In other words `:` takes an element and a list, appending this element to the list.

The equivalent expression for your example is:

```
tails1 ((:) x xs') = ((:)x xs'):tails1 xs'
```

Where `x` is holding the first element of the list and `xs'` the rest of the list. `xs'` cannot hold multiple elements. In your example `tails1 ((:) x ((:) xs' [])) = xs:tails1 xs'`, `xs'` should hold everything except first element and `[]`. (in my examle it should be 2:3:4 which is not a valid list because is not ended by []).

Answer (score 5):

In other answers, we have seen two proposals:

```
tailsA (x:xs') = (x:xs'):tailsA xs
tailsB xs = xs:tailsB (tail xs)
```

The former has the right denotational semantics, but the wrong operational semantics. The original `tails` has only one call to `(:)`; one might therefore worry that a sufficiently stupid compiler would allocate extra cons cells when running `tailsA` compared to the original definition of `tails`. The latter also has the right denotation, and only has one call to `(:)`, but inserts a brand new function `tail` which does not appear in the original; this transformation seems to require some programmer insight to perform. Below, I will show how the original definition may be transformed into one with no at-patterns in a way that does not require programmer insight (hence can be performed by a compiler) and which does not risk additional allocation.

```
tailsC xs = case xs of
    x:xs' -> xs:tailsC xs'
```

Of special interest here: the original equation's right-hand side appears verbatim as the right-hand side of the case statement. (Neither of `tailsA` or `tailsB` contains the original equation's right-hand side as a subterm at all.) The general translation of at patterns suggested by this special-case transformation is not fully correct (since `xs` matches any value whereas `xs@(x:xs')` matches only non-empty lists); a full treatment of turning Haskell-style patterns into GHC-Core-style case statements (which scrutinize only a single variable, and whose patterns all contain exactly one constructor) is out of scope for a StackOverflow answer. There have been several research papers discussing how to do this correctly, efficiently, and producing speedy code; see also the related question [Algorithm for type checking ML-like pattern matching?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7883023/791604) and basically all of the results in the Google Scholar search for [compiling pattern matching](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=compiling+pattern+matching).

But the basic idea is that `name@pattern` matches exactly when `pattern` matches (binding all the same names `pattern` does to all the same values), but additionally binds `name` to the full value.

Comment: Can you provide a reference to the general transformation (including correct pattern-matching)?

Answer (score 2):

Because the `tails1 []` entry comes first, we don't need to ensure that the desugared `tails1 xs@(x:xs')` only matches nonempty lists, as they are guaranteed to be nonempty.  Thus, the only effect of writing `xs@(x:xs')` is to give us access to both `xs` and `tail xs`, and so the line can be rewritten as:

```
tails1 xs = xs : tails1 (tail xs)
```